# Vsphere provisioning equivalent to virt-install's --location options?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vmware-vsphere, virt-install

Is there a Vsphere guest provisioning equivalent to KVM's virt-install --location?

> -l LOCATION , --location=LOCATION Distribution tree installtion source. virt-install can recognize certain distribution trees and
>   fetches a bootable kernel/initrd pair to launch the install.

Using this option with KVM one can provision Linux hosts without pxeboot or maintaining VMware images.

Comment: I don't think VMware vSphere has any comparable functionality.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please

Comment: @Chopper3 KVM/libvirt has a feature where a Linux OS can be installed simply by pointing to a URL containing a mirror of that Linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know that either :) - vSphere doesn't directly do that but you can deploy a template from a URL but it has to be a pre-build VM template - this could be a basic jumpstart image, you can PXE boot as you know, but otherwise I don't think it matches the same exact thing sorry.